# supertest test with jwt header token

Tags: express, jwt, superagent

I'm have some issue in my test with superagent and express.js.

```
it('should 200 with valid login', (done) => {
    console.log(createdUser[`${validUser.email}`]['token']);
    // JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ODAwZDllZmNiM2VkMzBhOGZmMDUyOGUiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJoYW5zIiwibGFzdE5hbWUiOiJvdHRvIiwiZW1haWwiOiJvdHRvQGV4YW1wbGUuZGUiLCJyb2xlIjoiVXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTQ3NjQ1MDc5OSwiZXhwIjoxNDc2NDYwODc5fQ.OlO_dVMCV6bm7XSyzKLFTgb-efOeyU1TniHEcIY7AHU
    request(app)
        .get('/api/protected')
        .set('Authorization', createdUser[`${validUser.email}`]['token'])
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res)=> {
            if (err) done(err);
            console.log(res.header);
            // assert(true, 'asdfasdf');
            // done();
        });
});
```

#### I can't access to the protected path over superagent.

When I'm accessing the path over Postman it is working and I can access the protected path with the suited jwt.

What do have to change in the code?
I want to test different paths.

thanks

Comment: No ideas here to sold that problem or is some information missing.

Answer (score 1):

Bearer keyword is missing while setting the token

`` .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${createdUser[`${validUser.email}`]['token']}`) ``

Answer (score 0):

There is some information missing but here are some possible answers:

1. You do show how you created your app. If you are using a middleware like express-jwt it needs to be configured before running your test. (app.use(expressJWt...)
2. Typically, the jwt is sent through the Authorization header using the **Bearer** schema. ( i.e. Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJI... )

Answer (score 0):

You can use superagent’s [`auth`](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#authentication) function with `{ type: ‘bearer’ }` option:

```js
request.auth(jwt, { type: 'bearer' })
```